# Django Ajax Update Div without Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to update `<strong id="vote_count">` without having the refresh the page. Currently, the ajax request gets posted, but I have to manually refresh to page to update the vote count. `recommendation.get_total_votes` is originally a function in `recommendation` model.

**html**

```
<div id="vote_count">Vote Count: {{ recommendation.get_total_votes }}</div>
<br>
<button class="upvotes" data-recommendation="{{ recommendation.id }}"   class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    Upvote1
</button>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).on("click", ".upvotes", function(){
    console.log('my message');
    var recommendationid = $(this).attr("data-recommendation");
    $.post('/upvote/', {recommendation_id: recommendationid}, function(data){
            console.log('my message1');
            $('#vote_count').html(data);
            $('#upvotes').hide();
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def upvote(request):
    recommendation_id = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        recommendation_id = request.POST['recommendation_id']
    get_total_votes = 0
    if recommendation_id:
        recommendation = coremodels.Recommendation.objects.get(id=int(recommendation_id))
        user = request.user
        recommendation.votes.up(user)
        get_total_votes = recommendation.votes.count()
    return HttpResponse(get_total_votes)
```

#### models.py (edit):

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    votes = VotableManager()

    def get_total_votes(self):
        total = self.votes.count()
        return int(total)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors from the JS? Like a parser error? Does `$('#vote_count').html(data);` get called?

Comment: Can you add a call to `alert()` or `console.log()` in your JS to see exactly  what is getting executed and include this information in your question?

Comment: @IanAuld Updated code with my console.log() http://i.imgur.com/i5YtW5s.png

Comment: @Emma put it in the ajax callback function and see if it gets called.

Comment: @rady yes it does get called. updating question http://i.imgur.com/bFUnlsh.png

Comment: @Emma Print out data. see if data is what you expect

Comment: @rady data is correct. it is printing out 2 (originally 1 before casting the vote) http://i.imgur.com/d2gkw6g.png - could this be an issue with `{{ recommendation.get_total_votes }}` This is originally calling a function inside the recommendation model. Updating question with the `models.py`.

Comment: You should include that function here. If it is doing something differently that could be it. Does `#vote_count` not go to 2 at all?

Comment: @rady I included the function in the updated question. Vote_count goes to 2 only when the page is refreshed.

Comment: I think it is preferred to use `$.text` vs `$.html`. `$.html` treats the string as an html string (2 is obviously not a valid html string). `$.text` will treat it as a text string.

Comment: If you change `console.log('my message1');` to `console.log(data);` what gets printed to the console?

Comment: @IanAuld console log prints 2. @rady replacing `.html` with `.text` does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the trouble shooting. I was able to work around this issue by changing

```
$('#vote_count').html(data);
$('#upvotes').hide();
```

to

```
$('.vote_count').html(data);
$('.upvotes').hide();
```

And use `class` instead of `id` tags in html. Still unsure why `id` tags are not working.

Comment: Do you more than one element with id `vote_count` (which should be `vote-count` HTML uses dashes not underscores) on your page?